# How to select users with only addrss values is null

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a able contains multiple records for each user some of them is null,

```
username address
erick    
erick    
samara   
samara   New York
denis    
denis    

expected result: 
erick
denis
```

how to write a query retrieve users who have no address value in table

I tried this but not work at all

**"select username from table_name where address is group by username"** this returns "samara" as well which already got a record with address is not null

Answer (score 3):

```
select username 
from table_name 
group by username
having sum(case when address is not null then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

or

```
having max(address) is null
```

Comment: The question is for all-NULL addresses, so I inverted the logic on the code.

Answer (score 2):

You need something like:

```
SELECT username 
FROM tablename
WHERE username 
NOT IN
  (
    SELECT username FROM tablename 
    WHERE address IS NOT NULL
  )
GROUP BY username;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
select username from table
minus
select username from table where address is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can choose users with "NULL as address by using **where address is null** and can chose one row for each user by using **distinct**. No need to use group by clause.

```
select distinct username from table_name where address is null
and username not in (select username from table_name where address is not null)
```